# Jquery Ajax call going to error inspite of data coming correctly in action method in controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have written an action method inside a controller to get data from database and return the json data,I have called the action method through ajax call in jquery,My problem is Data is fetching correctly,also action method returning that data correctly but in ajax call it is going to error method dont know why?

My code for controller action method is:

```
  public JsonResult LoadDataDirection()
    {

        var list = (from t in db.GoldenVolumes
                    select t).Take(10000).Distinct().ToList();
        var querygroupByRegion =
           from a in list
           group a by a.DestinationRegion;
        return Json(querygroupByRegion, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Ajax call for calling this method is:

var URL = "/VolumeReport/LoadDataDirection";

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        LOCAL_DATA_JSON = getLocalData(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        alert('Failed to retrieve Data.');

    }
});
```

VolumeReport is my controller Name

Comment: What errors do you get in the console and in the Network response?

Comment: Remove type: Get from the AJAX

Comment: Its giving status 500,readystate=4,status text="Internal Server Error"

Comment: That means you controller is throwing an exception. Use you browser tools to inspect the response in the network tab

Comment: actually response text in error is coming as :-"Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property." Can you tell me what is that and how to slve that

Comment: You have to set "maxJsonLength" property in your web.config file. <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000000">

Comment: Yes I had added maxJsonLength thing in web.config but it didnt worked....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everyone.I Have got the solution.I have used in my controller

```
 public ContentResult LoadDataDirection()
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        var list = (from t in db.GoldenVolumes
                    select t).Take(10000).Distinct().ToList();
        var querygroupByRegion =
           from a in list
           group a by a.DestinationRegion;
        var result = new ContentResult
        {
            Content = serializer.Serialize(querygroupByRegion),
            ContentType = "application/json"
        };
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This is not correct, how come you put a random answer and u think it is the solution

Answer (score 0):

In View Do something like:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("LoadDataDirection","VolumeReport")',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(ex));
     }
});

public JsonResult LoadDataDirection()
{

    var list = (from t in db.GoldenVolumes
                select t).Take(10000).Distinct().ToList();
    var querygroupByRegion =
       from a in list
       group a by a.DestinationRegion;
    return Json(querygroupByRegion, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Read comments below his question and check what he wrote var URL = "/VolumeReport/LoadDataDirection"; his controller is not named as 'home'. Read carefully

Comment: Thank for attention. Actually question was edited after I was creating solution. @Marcin